# HOW TO USE SUM WITH INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Ok I have here

```
tbl_one
    id
    amount
tbl_two
    id
    amount
```

is it posible to get the `sum` of amount in `tbl_one` and `tbl_two` using inner join ?? can someone know how to do it ? THANKS IN ADVANCE .

Comment: Please post some sample data and the required result. It seems that you want to calculate `SUM` on a `UNION` between two queries.

Comment: i was thinking if it's posible ? data on the amount is integer any number , i just want to get the sum of the `tbl_one.amount` and `tbl_two.amount` using inner join

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28523826/2055998) what are you looking for?  If not, clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can join on id:

```
SELECT a.id, sum(a.amount+b.amount) as total
      from tbl_one as a JOIN tbl_two as b
      ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

That is also assuming that you need to group, otherwise you can drop the sum and the GROUP BY.